# proving a theorem from limit using Hopital rule

Tags: calculus

If $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=\infty$, then 
$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x)^{g(x)} = e^{\lim_{x\to a}g(x)(f(x)-1)}.$$
How can one prove this theorem?

Comment: One can show that $\lim_{x\to a} \ln(f(x))g(x) - (f(x)-1)g(x) = \lim_{x\to a} (\frac{1}{f(x)} -1)\frac{f'(x)}{-g(x)^2g'(x)} = \lim_{x\to a} (\frac{1}{f(x)} -1) \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f'(x)}{-g(x)^2g'(x)} = 0$.

Comment: @Nex That should be an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enough to show
$$\lim_{x\to a}g(x)\ln f(x)=\lim_{x\to a}g(x)\bigl(f(x)-1\bigr)$$
As $f(x)\to 1$ when $x\to a$, this results from $\ln f(x)=\ln\bigl(1+f(x)-1\bigr)\sim_a f(x)-1$, hence 
$$g(x)\ln f(x)\sim_a g(x)\bigl(f(x)-1\bigr).$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x)^{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to a} [1+(f(x)-1)]^{g(x)}$$
$$ = \lim_{x \to a} \left([1+(f(x)-1)]^{\left(\frac{1}{f(x)-1}\right)}\right)^{g(x)(f(x)-1)}$$
$$= \lim_{f(x) \to f(a)} \left([1+(f(x)-1)]^{\left(\frac{1}{f(x)-1}\right)}\right)^{g(x)(f(x)-1)}$$
$$= \lim_{[f(x)-1] \to 0} \left([1+(f(x)-1)]^{\left(\frac{1}{f(x)-1}\right)}\right)^{g(x)(f(x)-1)}$$
$$=e^{\lim_{x \to a}g(x)(f(x)-1)}$$